# How do you update input text value based on user input and display the value? (CRUD app update/save feature)

Tags: javascript, crud

I'm currently building a CRUD app so users can keep track of books they have read or haven't read. Im currently trying to implement an update/edit feature so the user can update the book info if he/she wishes. The issue I'm having is, whenever I try to save the book info after changing the input values, the last book in 'myLibrary' array would get the info instead of the current book I'm trying to update. The only time the current book gets the user input is when it's the only book in the array :(

I tried using the array splice() method to replace the current book with a new book that has the new info/values but I'm still having the same problem.

```js
// book class: represents a book

class Book {
  constructor(title, author, pages, read) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.pages = pages;
    this.read = read;
  }
}

// array to store books.. default books using the Book Constructor

let myLibrary = [{
    title: 'Dark Matter',
    author: 'Blake Crouch',
    read: 'read',
    pages: 342,
  },
  {
    title: '1984',
    author: 'Geroge Orwell',
    read: 'not read',
    pages: 328
  },
];

/* saves the updated user input on click and closes modal
removes the book from the library array and adds the updated book to the library array and saves it to local storage again with updated info from user input in the form fields in the modal window and closes the modal window after submission of the form fields */

saveBtn.addEventListener('click', (index) => {
  myLibrary.splice(myLibrary.indexOf(index), 1);
  addBookToLibrary();
  setData();
  render();
  document.querySelector('.modal').classList.add('modal--hidden');
  hideBackgroundFade();
  clearForm();
});
```

[clip of the UI... showing the bug](https://i.imgur.com/STwRJvv.mp4)

Comment: Hi Keron, welcome to Stack Overflow. For people to help you, you need to provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You need to review the [syntax for `.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#syntax). The parameter for the callback is _not_ some index of something - it is the event object.

Comment: I did but still couldn’t resolve the issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say w/o more code, esp. the HTML structure or a framework you might use. So assuming the following HTML structure:

```
    <div class='books'>
        <div book-id="123">
            <h1>Title 1</h1>
            <p>200 pages</p>
        </div>
        <div book-id="456">
            <h1>Title 2</h1>
            <p>100 pages</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

To be most generic, i.e. any click would link your UI to the data source, your script might could look sg like:

```
  const books = document.querySelector('.books');
  books.addEventListener("click", evt => {
      const book = evt.target.closest("[book-id]");
      if (book) {
          const bookId = book.getAttribute("book-id");
          const bookInLib = myLibrary.find( elem => elem.id == bookId )
          // here you update your book and trigger rendering
      }
  })
```

Comment: Sorry, the books are stored in an array: `myLibrary = []` and the html is  `<div id='bookShelf'></div>` I append the elements I created in the javascript file to this div using a createBook() function which creates the book visual and add it to DOM (bookShelf) element in index.html file then render it to the browser

Comment: `function render() {
        const display = document.getElementById('bookShelf');
        const books = document.querySelectorAll('.book');
        books.forEach((book) => display.removeChild(book));

        for (let i = 0; i < myLibrary.length; i++) {
                createBook(myLibrary[i]);
        }
}`

Comment: I added this code to the saveBtn function.... It updates the book and add it to end of the array but if I edit the same book twice in a row or the last book in the array ill get duplicates... it replaces the first book with a book that has the last book input values  `myLibrary.splice(myLibrary.indexOf[0], 1);
                addBookToLibrary();
                setData();
                render();
                clearForm();
                removeModal();`
        }
});`